# Why is my USB 3.1 gen 2 adapter (USB C Female to USB A Male) causing bottlenecking?

Tags: windows-10, usb-storage, usb-3, usb-3.1-type-c

I recently picked up an SSD and enclosure with a built in USB Cable. CrystalDiskMark shows a >500MB/s read speed and >400MB/s write speed with a direct USB C connection to a USB 3.1 gen 2 port, so all good here.

But I also picked up [these adaptors from amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/aceyoon-Charger-Connector-Extension-Converter/dp/B078HRTQG7/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1528127320&sr=1-1&keywords=USB+3.1+gen+2+A+Male+to+USB+Type+C+Female) to ensure I could connect the drive to more common USB type A ports. These adapters noted that they could handle the 10Gbit speeds of USB 3.1 gen 2, although they do note that when this is the case the "other side" (Type A side) runs at USB 2 speeds. Out of a lack of options I decided to give them a go nonetheless and the claim is true. But it's not as simple as saying "these must really just be USB 2 adaptors with a blue finish".

When using the adapter to connect the drive to a front panel USB 3.1 **gen 1** port connected to the USB 3 motherboard header, the speeds are ~300MB/s and 400MB/s read and write respectively. So the adapter can handle high throughput but just can't when used in gen 1 or 2 ports on the IO panel of the motherboard itself. Maybe this is a motherboard issue...

**Edit:** Just verified this across 2 Desktop systems:

- Rear Motherboard IO (USB 3.1 gen 1 and gen 2) with adapter: ~40BM/s
  R/W
- Rear Motherboard USB C with no adapter ~500MB/s R and ~400MB/s W
  (full speed)
- Front panel IO connected to motherboard USB 3 header (gen 1) with
  adapter ~200MB/s R ~400MB/s W

What am I missing here? I have found [only one adapter available](http://www.delock.de/produkte/G_65698/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) that clearly states it has 10Gbit ports at either end but it's pricey so any alternative suggestions are welcome. Notably, it has a significant rectangle shape at the USB C side, maybe this is part of the explanation...? See below:

[image]

Comment: I thought "USB 3.0" and "USB 3.1 Gen1" were the same thing?

Comment: That is true, I should probably rephrase my question for clarity. The USB 3.0 ports mentioned here are front panel ports connected to the USB 3 header in the motherboard, whereas the 3.1s are part of the motherboard IO at the rear of the case.

Comment: Please name the motherboard’s make and model.

Comment: So, after trying to make sense of the product description, I think I finally got it (though it doesn’t make a lot of sense): When the *host* is connected to the adapter on the USB-C side, it supports only USB 2.0 speeds, for whatever reason. It’s not “the other side” but “the other way/direction”.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - the mothoboards are both MSI x270s, where the x is 1 or 2 for each system tested respectively. I also read that product description and can't say I understand the technicalities of why that restriction applies, but in either case it wouldn't explain why the front panel ports allow a faster data rate than the rear ones, as the adapter is used in the same discretion in either case. I do appreciate the help though! I might get the more expensive adapter to solve this problem reliably.

Comment: "while the other side runs at USB 2 speeds" - This means the adapter runs at USB 2.0 speeds.  USB 2.0 isn't capable of 10 Gbit speeds and the connector is USB 3.0.  The accuracy of products listed on Amazon is the responsibility of the seller.

Comment: @Ramhound If that were true, bullet point 3 would not be possible, as transfer speeds of >60MB/s (Megabytes per second) would not be possible? I do appreciate your input

Comment: @Sam3000 If what was true?  The description of the product indicates it runs at USB 2.0 speeds.  The product description indicates it's a USB 3.0 device.  The accuracy of the listed product description is not verified by anyone at Amazon.  [Here](http://www.aceyoon.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=52) is the product description per the manufacturer.  It appears the Amazon product description is wrong.  (Can't verify myself though aceyoon is blocked)

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I'll clarify: if the problem here is that the device runs at USB 2 speeds, then it would not have been possible to achieve the speeds shown in the third bullet point using it.

Comment: @Sam3000 - You assume the third bullet is an accurate description.  If a USB 3.1 GEN 2 device is connected to a host over USB 3.0 (per the product description) then it's not possible for it to have USB 3.1 GEN 1 speeds.  *The adapter converts a Type-C connect to a USB 3.0.*  It would be no different if you had a USB Type-C to USB 3.0 cable (and/or a Type-C HUB with a USB 3.0 cable).

Comment: @Ramhound Those numbers are my own tests rather than assumptions, I understand your point though, thank you